# jquery automatic return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

in this code what does the function return ?and that value is assigned to id attribute of each div.I found that it is returning div-id0 for first div,div-id1 for second div.why this is happening?

```
$("div").attr("id", function (arr) {
  return "div-id" + arr;
})
```

Comment: A look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) reveals: `.attr( attributeName, function(index, attr) )`. So `arr` is the index of the element in the set of elements.

Answer (score 3):

If you supply a function as the second argument to `attr`, the function is executed once for each element in the selection and the return value is set as the attribute value of that element.

The position in the selection is passed as the first argument to the callback; the current value of the attribute is passed as the second argument.

```
$("div").attr("id", function (arr) {
  return "div-id" + arr;
})
```

So this code sets the `id` of every `div` element to `div-id` plus the position of the element in the selection.  So the first will be `div-id0`, the second `div-id1`, etc.

It would be better to name the argument `index`, rather than the confusing `arr`.

Answer (score 2):

See http://api.jquery.com/attr/

In the documentation

`.attr( attributeName, function(index, attr) )`

> `attributeName` The name of the attribute to set.
>
> `function(index, attr)` A function returning the value to set. this is the current element. **Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old attribute value as arguments.**

Answer (score 2):

When passing a function to [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) or [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css) in jQuery, the first parameter passed to the function is the current **array index**, and the second parameter is the current value of the property you are trying to set for **the current element**.